# Bluetooth RFComm Android

Tags: pi-3, serial, bluetooth

I am attempting to setup a rfcomm channel inside of an android application. I can successfully pair to the phone (Bluetooth) via the GUI. However, if I use some sort of Terminal app on the phone (in my case I'm using BlueTerm), I am unsuccessfully in establishing a connection.

I have followed the instructions found here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=138145&f=28 and I'm still unsuccessful.

Has anyone had any success with such a thing?